# setMuted or setVolume do not work on iPad in MediaElement.js

Tags: ipad, mediaelement.js

It appears that neither volume controls nor mute/unmute work on iPad. Did anyone encounter this problem before? Pretty straightforward functionality, no errors, just silent fail.

```
var player;
$(document).ready(function () {
    player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player', {});
});
function mute() {
    player.setMuted(true)
    //  player.setVolume(0) does not work either on iPad

}
function unmute() {
    player.setMuted(false)
}
```

HTML:

```
 <audio id="player" controls="controls">
<source type="audio/mp3" src="intro.mp3" /> </audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Since MediaElement.js uses native `<audio>` controls on iPad, according to Safari HTML5 Audio and Video guide, it is not possible to control HTML5 audio volume via script:

> On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

... need to program a workaround for iPads.